# Dynamic Columns Based on User Selection (Laravel)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables

i have a question, what i want to achieve is something like this:
I'm using Laravel in my project, but i want to let every user customize his own tables views (show or hide columns)
For example, in the next image i have three columns:

[First Header]

[image: fh]

But i want to let the user pick (show or hide) the columns he wants,

[Extra Columns]

[image: ec]

How do i achieve something like that?
I am using Laravel and Jquery Datatables for the tables views.

I was thinking of create a table in the database which can store the columns (in a json) for every user and each module.
I'd like to know if there is a better approach.

Thanks in advance, blessings!

Comment: [DataTables button extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) provides a [column visibility plug-in](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/index.html) that does what you want. It stores the column visibility in LocalStorage, [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/stateSave.html) is an example.

Comment: @Remul, sorry for the late answer, thank you so much. I'm using your solution and is working just fine, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Remul said in his comment, Datatable has its own functions (stateSaveCallback and stateLoadCallback)
Mixing that with State saving gave me what i needed

https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback
https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback